# Preventing `xmlValue` from stripping <br /> tags

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I'm having a problem wherein `xmlValue` strips the `<br />` tags that I need kept (or transformed to some other character that I can then `strsplit` on.

Here's an example:

```
> f <- htmlParse(getForm("http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/store_locator_popups.jsp", ajax="true", storeNumber=1889), asText=TRUE)
> xpathSApply(f, "//div[@class=\"sl_results_popup_address\"]", xmlValue)
[1] "1154 S Clark StChicago, IL 60605(312) 212-6300"
```

Versus the HTML it's parsing:

```
<div class="sl_results_popup_address">
1154 S Clark St
<br/>
Chicago, IL 60605
<br/>
(312) 212-6300
</div>
```

I've tried `, recursive=FALSE` but that doesn't seem to help.

If they were `<p>` and `</p>` line breaks then it would be easier since I could just grab them individually, but with `<br/>` not wrapping the text I really can't go that direction.  Hoping there's just an option to reduce the level of stripping done within `xmlValue` (or maybe the `<br/>`s are being stripped at the parsing-of-document phase?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

two things may help

```
app.data<-getForm("http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/store_locator_popups.jsp", ajax="true", storeNumber=1889)
app.data<-gsub("<br>","\n",app.data)
f <- htmlParse(app.data, asText=TRUE)
out<-xpathSApply(f, "//div[@class=\"sl_results_popup_address\"]", xmlValue)
> xpathSApply(f, "//div[@class=\"sl_results_popup_address\"]", xmlValue)
[1] "1154 S Clark St\nChicago, IL 60605\n(312) 212-6300"
>
```

so just replace the `br` tags with something else or use your original code and

```
> xpathSApply(f, "//div[@class=\"sl_results_popup_address\"]/text()", xmlValue)
[1] "1154 S Clark St"   "Chicago, IL 60605" "(312) 212-6300"   
>
```

if you want to keep the tags

```
dum.fun<-function(x){if(xmlName(x)=="br"){"<br/>"}else{xmlValue(x)}}
xChild<-xpathSApply(f, "//div[@class=\"sl_results_popup_address\"]",xmlChildren)
lapply(xChild,dum.fun)
> unlist(lapply(xChild,dum.fun))
[1] "1154 S Clark St"   "<br/>"             "Chicago, IL 60605"
[4] "<br/>"             "(312) 212-6300" 
>
```

Comment: Two lovely solutions.  Thanks.  I hadn't thought about `text()`.  Still getting used to xpath.  Much to learn, as always.

Comment: I copied the code from FireBug, so maybe that's where the difference came from.