# How to keep line breaks in XML elements in R

Tags: r, xml

I try to get the *xmlValue* of following xml structure:

```
<span class="a">ABC<br/>XYZ</span>
```

I would like to keep the br linebreak tag, but *xmlValue* seems to remove linebreaks:

```
library(XML)
doc = xmlTreeParse("sample.xml", useInternal = TRUE)
top<-xmlRoot(doc)
xmlValue(top)

[1] "ABCXYZ"
```

Is there a way to get the output including the linebreak?

```
[1] "ABC
     XYZ"
```

Or

```
[1] "ABC\nXYZ"
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11741318/8436923

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was hoping someone else would provide a better solution to this question.  Here is a solution using the xml2 package (I prefer this package over xml).

In this solution I use the `gsub` function from base R to replace all of the `<br/>` tags with a line return character `/n`.

```
library(xml2)

#Read in as a xml document
text<-read_xml('<span class="a">ABC<br/>XYZ</span>')

#substitute /n in for the line breaks.  
#gsub returns a character string, need to use read_xml to convert back to a xml document
two<-read_xml(gsub("<br/>", "/n", text))
#find the desired node(s)
xml_text(xml_find_all(two, "//span"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I also thought there might be a better solution. But it works :) Thanks!